# Offset commit failed on partition ecs.sendEventsV1-8 at offset 40576817: This is not the correct coordinator

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel, kafka-consumer-api

I see the below `warn` messages from `KafkaConsumer` for a span of few minutes abruptly while it was processing.

```
2020-12-08 00:40:20.874+0000 WARN  Camel (camel-1) thread #12 - KafkaConsumer[ecs.sendEventsV1] [clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator(handle:865)] [Consumer clientId=consumer-11, groupId=sendEventTest] Offset commit failed on partition ecs.sendEventsV1-8 at offset 40576817: This is not the correct coordinator.
2020-12-08 00:40:20.874+0000 WARN  Camel (camel-1) thread #13 - KafkaConsumer[ecs.sendEventsV1] [clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator(handle:865)] [Consumer clientId=consumer-12, groupId=sendEventTest] Offset commit failed on partition ecs.sendEventsV1-14 at offset 40576535: This is not the correct coordinator.
2020-12-08 00:40:20.875+0000 INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #12 - KafkaConsumer[ecs.sendEventsV1] [clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator(markCoordinatorUnknown:780)] [Consumer clientId=consumer-11, groupId=sendEventTest] Group coordinator KafkaBroker1:9093 (id: 2147482646 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
2020-12-08 00:40:20.875+0000 INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #13 - KafkaConsumer[ecs.sendEventsV1] [clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator(markCoordinatorUnknown:780)] [Consumer clientId=consumer-12, groupId=sendEventTest] Group coordinator KafkaBroker1:9093 (id: 2147482646 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
2020-12-08 00:40:20.978+0000 INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #12 - KafkaConsumer[ecs.sendEventsV1] [clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator(onSuccess:728)] [Consumer clientId=consumer-11, groupId=sendEventTest] Discovered group coordinator KafkaBroker2:9093 (id: 2147482643 rack: null)
2020-12-08 00:40:21.029+0000 INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #13 - KafkaConsumer[ecs.sendEventsV1] [clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator(onSuccess:728)] [Consumer clientId=consumer-12, groupId=sendEventTest] Discovered group coordinator KafkaBroker2:9093 (id: 2147482643 rack: null)
2020-12-08 00:40:21.205+0000 WARN  Camel (camel-1) thread #13 - KafkaConsumer[ecs.sendEventsV1] [clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator(handle:865)] [Consumer clientId=consumer-12, groupId=sendEventTest] Offset commit failed on partition ecs.sendEventsV1-14 at offset 40576535: The coordinator is loading and hence can't process requests.
2020-12-08 00:40:21.205+0000 WARN  Camel (camel-1) thread #12 - KafkaConsumer[ecs.sendEventsV1] [clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator(handle:865)] [Consumer clientId=consumer-11, groupId=sendEventTest] Offset commit failed on partition ecs.sendEventsV1-8 at offset 40576817: The coordinator is loading and hence can't process requests.
2020-12-08 00:40:21.310+0000 WARN  Camel (camel-1) thread #13 - KafkaConsumer[ecs.sendEventsV1] [clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator(handle:865)] [Consumer clientId=consumer-12, groupId=sendEventTest] Offset commit failed on partition ecs.sendEventsV1-14 at offset 40576535: The coordinator is loading and hence can't process requests.
2020-12-08 00:40:21.310+0000 WARN  Camel (camel-1) thread #12 - KafkaConsumer[ecs.sendEventsV1] [clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator(handle:865)] [Consumer clientId=consumer-11, groupId=sendEventTest] Offset commit failed on partition ecs.sendEventsV1-8 at offset 40576817: The coordinator is loading and hence can't process requests.
2020-12-08 00:40:21.415+0000 WARN  Camel (camel-1) thread #13 - KafkaConsumer[ecs.sendEventsV1] [clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator(handle:865)] [Consumer clientId=consumer-12, groupId=sendEventTest] Offset commit failed on partition ecs.sendEventsV1-14 at offset 40576535: The coordinator is loading and hence can't process requests.
2020-12-08 00:40:21.415+0000 WARN  Camel (camel-1) thread #12 - KafkaConsumer[ecs.sendEventsV1] [clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator(handle:865)] [Consumer clientId=consumer-11, groupId=sendEventTest] Offset commit failed on partition ecs.sendEventsV1-8 at offset 40576817: The coordinator is loading and hence can't process requests.
2020-12-08 00:40:21.567+0000 WARN  Camel (camel-1) thread #13 - KafkaConsumer[ecs.sendEventsV1] [clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator(handle:865)] [Consumer clientId=consumer-12, groupId=sendEventTest] Offset commit failed on partition ecs.sendEventsV1-14 at offset 40576535: The coordinator is loading and hence can't process requests.
```

This pattern is often seen.
This topic has 30 partitions, we have deployed 4 instances of the consumer application and each one of them defined with 2 consumer threads

```
consumersCount=2
consumerStreams=2
autoOffsetReset=latest
metadataMaxAgeMs=5000
autoCommitIntervalMs=5000
autoCommitEnable=False
allowManualCommit=True
consumerRequestTimeoutMs=300000
heartbeatIntervalMs=1000
maxPollIntervalMs=900000
maxPollRecords=100
sessionTimeoutMs=600000
```

I am using camel version `3.2.0` with `camel-kafka` version as `2.4.0`.
The broker version is also `2.4.0`

Any help would be appreciated to understand why do I see these error related to incorrect coordinator or not able to load the request.

Comment: any pause() or rebalancing happened before this log?

Comment: yes there is a rebalancing